# Automatically pass a value to a script menu for automation's sake in Bash/KSH

Tags: linux, bash, menu, automation, ksh

Trying to make a small script and cron job it in order to automate a task. Said script runs another script which has already been created, grabs the output, emails to specified recipients, and cleans up the output. I've got it almost down however am running into one major issue. The script that mine is running has a menu on the outset. That is to say, running the script by itself manually, i would have to select option 1 in order to get the output i want (the only other option, 2, is quit.)

How can I automatically enter (or simulate entering) the value 1 into the other script, so it does not hang when in a cron job waiting for user input?

Is there a sane way to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How is that script reading the input?

Comment: I believe this is the section of interest: `PS3="Choose a number:"
if [[ $OS = "LINUX" ]]
        then
        select CHOICE in CUPS Quit
        do
                case $CHOICE in
                        CUPS)   print_sys_cups;;
                        Quit)   exit;;
                        *)              echo Invalid Choice;;
                esac
        done
`

Comment: Try `echo 1 | script.sh`.

Comment: works like a charm. not sure why i didn't think about that. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something as simple as using `yes | command` if answering yes is all that is needed.  Otherwise you probably want to use expect to drive the imaginary keyboard for you.

http://expect.sourceforge.net/

Using autoexpect to record your session is a convenient way to come up with rough draft expect scripts as well.